# PHP echo input boxes on every row & POST info

Tags: php

I'm pulling info into an array from a python script.  My goals was to display the array in a table (complete), I'm also adding two input boxes per table row (complete but not sure if I'm doing it right), and I intend to pass the input information from the input boxes back to a python script to update the data (and no its not updating a database).

My challenge is I have an input box on each line, but when I try to pass the data from the input box it only passes info from the last set of boxes.  I've been digging around and cant seem to find my solution.  As you can see in the sample code, currently only only attempting to print/POST the results the page to test my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $data = $_POST['type'];
    $data1 = explode(" ", $data);
    $data2 = $data[0];
    $data3 = $data[1];
    $data4 = $data[2];
}

$output = json_decode(shell_exec("python/var/www/html/common_deploy/.../test4123/test4123.py $data $data1 $data2 $data3"), TRUE);

$var = $output[0];
$var1 = $output[1];
$var2 = $output[2];
$var3 = $output[3];
$var4desc_a = $output[4];
$var4desc_b = $output[5];

?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">

    <?php

    echo "<table>";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {

        echo "<tr>   
                <td>" . $var[$i] . "</td>    
                <td>" . $var1[$i] . "</td>   
                <td>" . $var2[$i] . "</td>   
                <td>" . $var3[$i] . "</td>   
                <td>" . $var4desc_a[$i] . "</td>     
                <td>" . $var4desc_b[$i] . "</td>     
                <td><input name='newdesc_a' type='text'/></td>   
                <td><input name='newdesc_b' type='text'/></td>

                </tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"></form>


<?php echo $_POST["newdesc_a"]; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST["newdesc_b"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you either need to give them unique names or make them array-like inputs `name='newdesc_a[]'`

Comment: Check the values of the variables with `var_dump($var); var_dump($var1);` etc, and also `var_dump($output);` It most likely does not contain what you think it does.

Comment: The inputs in each loop have the same name, so it will only echo the last row's value. You could use an array for the names (e.g., `name='newdesc_a[]'`) to save input values as an array

Comment: I would suggest `newdesc[a][]` and `newdesc[b][]`

Comment: Also, if $output is null, then the json_decode failed. Try assigning the results of your shell_exec to a variable, verify the contents of that variable, then try to use json_decode.

Comment: I thought I could make them arrays, but I couldnt POST/print them.